# python regex match single quote

Tags: python, regex

I try to match single quote in below:

```
s= "name:'abc','hello'"
```

but seems the behaviour of match/findall is different:

```
re.match("\B'\w+'\B", s)   # ===> return None

re.findall("\B'\w+'\B", s)  #===> RETURN ['abc', 'hello']
```

actually this is caused by single quotes in the string, anyone knows what's going on?

I'm using py2.7.8 in win7.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) brother, it clearly states that `match()`: "checks for a match only at the beginning of the string"

Answer (score 7):

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match -- "Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default)."

You're using `re.match()`; if you switch to `re.search()`, you'll get the behavior you were expecting.